# Powershell: Check folderpermissions on server and export to local computer

Tags: powershell, server, permissions

Good day,
I want to check the folderpermissions on a server and export the results as a csv to a shared folder on the local computer.
I thought enter-pssession was the way to go, but it cannot find the folder that I want to check.
It looks like it is looking for that folder on the local computer, not on the server.

This is what I have got:

```
#Start of script

#Get Servername
$Servername = Read-Host -Prompt "Servername"
$Adminusername = Read-Host -Prompt "Admin user name"

#Connect to the server
Enter-PSsession $Servername -Credential $Adminusername

#Get the Directory
$Directory = Read-Host -Prompt "What directory and subfolders do you want to check (f.e. E:\Data\Shared_Data)?"

#Define location of export file
$path = "\\shared folder on local computer\"
$Logdate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmm
$csvfile = $path + "\Permissions_$Servername_$LogDate.csv"

#Scan for directories under shared folder and get permissions for all of them
dir -Recurse $Directory | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv -path $csvfile -NoTypeInformation -inputObject { $_; Write-Progress "Exporting to CSV" "$($_) " }

Write-Host
Write-Host "Export completed"
Write-Host
Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to return to the menu”

#End of script
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: to start, you need to tell us what you expected and what you actually got

Comment: i agree with @sirtao. Its not clear what you are trying to do. It looks like you are trying to map to a remote computer and then copy a csv file from it? 
What happens when you run your script ?